# How to parse nested JSON object in android

Tags: android, json

I want to parse the verse_nr and verse from the bellow JSON data.can anyone help me..

```
{"book":[{"book_ref":"Ps","book_name":"Psalms","book_nr":"19","chapter_nr":"16","chapter":{"8":{"verse_nr":"8","verse":"I have set the LORD always before me: because he is at my right hand, I shall not be moved."}}}],"direction":"LTR","type":"verse","version":"kjv"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a JSON Parser library. Here's an example with [org.json.](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) parser.

```
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(inputJSON);

JSONObject chapter = root.getJSONArray("book")
                         .getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("chapter");
JSONObject verse = chapter.getJSONObject(JSONObject.getNames(chapter)[0]);
```

Basically, you just chain the JSON *getters* till you reach the `verse` object. Once there, you can access the values with `getString()` as

```
System.out.println(verse.getString("verse_nr"));
System.out.println(verse.getString("verse"));
```

***Output :***

> 8
>   I have set the LORD always before me: because he is at my right hand, I shall not be moved.

Comment: Glad to help. I hope you noticed why I used `JSONObject.getNames(chapter)[0]`? That's because the *key* `"8"` in `chapter` node would, I guess, vary always.

Answer (score 0):

You must iterate over it using `JSONObject` and `JSONArray`.

You can generate classes using: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ Just make sure to check 'Json' as opposed to 'Json Schema' since this is the raw json. Then you can use gson to automatically turn this into the those generated classes. A guide on doing so: 
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

If this is coming from a server, I'd recommend using the wonderful Retrofit library which would allow you to do all the above with just a few lines of code; a tutorial of doing this can be found here: http://inaka.net/blog/2014/10/10/android-retrofit-rest-client/

Anyways if want to ignore making your life easier with the above solutions, to manually do this you'll do something like the following:

`String jsonLiteral = /* your json remember to escape the double quotes */
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(jsonLiteral);
// Get Strings from a JSONObject as
String direction = root.getString("direction");
// You have a single element array, so you need to get that
JSONObject singleElement = root.getJSONArray("book").getJSONObject(0);
// Then you can Strings from it like direction above
String bookRef = singleElement.getString("book_ref");`

You can also get a pretty output to inspect the json structure by using:
http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/